# MVC 5 scaffolding not emitting bootstrap classes for basic EF derived data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

First off, I'm a newcomer to MVC and ASP.NET so apologies if I'm missing something simple.

I'm working on a code first MVC 5 application, for the sake of brevity lets say I have two Models defined like this:

```
public class Platform
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "You must select a manufacturer")]
    [DisplayName("Manufacturer")]
    public int ManufacturerId { get; set; }
    public virtual Manufacturer Manufacturer { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="You must enter a name for the platform")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage="Reduce length to 50 characters or less")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class Manufacturer
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage="You must enter a name for the manufacturer")]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage="Reduce length to 50 characters or less")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Platform> Platforms { get; set; }
}
```

When creating 'MVC 5 Controller with views, using Entity Framework' scaffolding for these models all the CRUD actions are working correctly. The form elements on the other hand are unformatted, missing the `form-control` class that Bootstrap wants.

I can work around this per type by adding an EditorTemplate with something like `@Html.TextBox("", ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue, new { @class = "form-control" })` in it, but surely the scaffolding for a Bootstrap MVC 5 project should be emitting valid code already? Looking at various MVC 5 tutorials they seem to be working correctly with proper styling, so I'm left somewhat confused as to what I'm doing wrong.

For reference, the output in the Create.cshtml file for each model (clipped to the important form elements for brevity) is:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ManufacturerId, "ManufacturerId", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("ManufacturerId", String.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ManufacturerId)
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
</div>
```

and

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
    </div>
</div>
```

Why is the `ManufacturerId` being specified as the label text for the drop down when a `DisplayName` is set in the model?

Why is the drop down using `DropDownList()` instead of the strongly typed `DropDownListFor()`?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you did what I did - upgrade Bootstrap 2.x to 3.0 or 3.0.1. The Microsoft project templates are based on Bootstrap 2.x not 3.x. You can read about others bumping into on
[GitHub](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/10957).

I also got a reply from Rick Anderson of Microsoft who wrote several of the Tutorials on www.asp.net and he confirmed this...

> Great catch. Actually, some of the images in my tutorial are from Beta and RC that are using bootstrap v2, not V3, so our images will differ. Look at the views for your account controller to see "form-control". You can download my complete project and compare with your project.

Regarding your other question, I ran into the same issue and think it may be a bug. Certain annotations appear to get ignored. Try adding a [ForeignKey()] annotation to Platform.ManufacturerId and see if it affects the field label.

Comment: You're right in that the scaffolding is emitting Bootstrap 2 code, but I haven't done any upgrades or anything. I just tested this with a fresh VM, and fresh install of VS2013, a brand new project, add models, create scaffolding: broken as above.

Comment: It would seem MS changed Bootstrap to v3 last minute for MVC5. The account pages are built with the correct styles - the scaffolding has not been updated to match. I watched a video of an introduction to scaffolding from MVC3 and the same bug with Id being appended to foreign key drop down labels was there then - the presenter said it was fixed for release - on MVC3!

Comment: It seems for now the conclusion is: MS have updated the project but not the scaffolding and it's a bug. I'll look for somewhere to report this or +1 a report. Thanks for the reply and the link, it at least makes me a feel a little better that it isn't something I'm doing wrong. The drop down not using `DropDownListFor()` is still a bit of a mystery though - no combination of data annotations seems to make that do what I expect it to. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I'm the author of that [Github issue](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/10957) you reference. Of course, I was a bit disappointed that mdo isn't planning on doing anything about it in Bootstrap. Rick Anderson [mentioned](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/introduction/adding-a-view) that they're going to *try* to add better support for it in 'Update 1'. Looking forward to that, because at the moment I'm not sure what's the right way to deal with it...

Comment: I'm new to MVC5, in fact, I'm still in VS 2012, and am using the [Web Tools 2013.1 add on](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/11/18/announcing-release-of-asp-net-and-web-tools-2013-1-for-visual-studio-2012.aspx) so I can create MVC5 projects/templates. How would I be able to spot if my scaffolding is off? It seems that my first attempt to scaffold a controller+views resulted in a NuGet-auto-retrieval of the Bootstrap 3 assets. FWIW - my packages.config says: "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc"  version="5.2.3".... oops.. I think the answer is to carefully read the OP!!!

Answer (score 6):

It looks like MVC 5.1 will have a workaround for the form-control problem with Bootstrap 3, as stated [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/12/09/asp-net-and-web-tools-2013-2-preview-for-visual-studio-2013.aspx). It will be possible to pass styles for EditorFor.

Comment: Thanks for posting, it's good to know they have some plan to support it. I wonder, will this have to be done on every EditorFor though? It hardly fits with DRY if so.

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like it. I also think it is not the optimal solution. We can hope it will at least be used as default when we scaffold a view.
I'll be testing MVC 5.1 in a few days, I'll edit my answer when I confirm how they solved this.

Comment: The syntax is: @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" }})